# Which domain to register a service name with DNS-SD when domain is assigned by DHCP server?

Tags: linux, dhcp, dns-sd

I want to register my device with DNS-SD and I have to register it in the domain assigned by the DHCP server. But how do I get the domain assigned by the DHCP server?

How should I know that a DHCP server has come up on the network and assigned my device new network configuration?
Also if DHCP server does not assign a domain, I shall register the service in local domain.

Can I extract domain from resolv.conf?

Answer (score 0):

`dhclient` periodically runs a script called `dhclient-script` (incidentally, this is also the script that updates the domain name when using DHCP). [`dhclient-script`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient-script) will check for the existence of `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-up-hooks` and run it when a new lease is assigned. Put your DNS-SD registration code inside that script.

The current domain name can be retrieved using [`dnsdomainname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dnsdomainname).